# Does Lua have a language standard?

Tags: lua

I was wondering if somebody more experienced that I can tell me if Lua has a language standard. I am new to programming, and so I would assume that the reference manual is the language standard. If this is not true, are there other documents that are possibly equivalent to a language standard? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried http://www.lua.org/docs.html?

Comment: Note that while the manual *does* define the standard, that doesn't prevent any embedded implementations from *deviating* from that standard (for instance, Garry's Mod extends the comment symbols to include `//`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated clearly on the [documentation](http://www.lua.org/docs.html) web site:

> The official definition of the Lua
>   language is its reference manual,
>   which describes the syntax and the
>   semantics of Lua, the standard
>   libraries, and the C API.

Comment: if you really want to get to grips I would also recommend Programming in Lua (Roberto Ierusalimschy)

Comment: @Jane T - +1 for PiL. I'd actually recommend reading it before the reference manual in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: I'd recommend, actually, having PiL side by side with the reference manual.